# Is 'device' synonymous with 'drive' in Unix-like OS's?

Tags: devices, terminology

In Unix/Linux terminology, are the words 'device' and 'drive' synonymous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Drives are devices, but not all devices are drives.

The [Wikipedia article on device files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) lists a number of non-drive devices.  For example, audio hardware is a device.  Serial & parallel ports are devices.  USB-connected gadgets are devices.

Keep in mind that some devices that are not drives may identify as such, a noteworthy example is most Android devices that identify as a drive but use a mechanism other than a drive unless it is mounted as USB storage.

Comment: thanks.  what are some devices that are not drives, for example?

Comment: but USB-connected gadgets are also drives, no?

Comment: @foampile, not if they're mice or keyboards or [missile launchers](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/8a0f/) or ...

Comment: oops, i meant USB thumb drives, cameras etc.

Comment: @foampile: "dumb" thumb drives usually present only a storage interface, but cameras could present other types of interface (light sensor, specialized i/o interface for software to control the camera, ...). Same thing with MP3 players, phones, ...

Comment: @foampile A good samples are HASP keys and BlueTooth adapters: Is it a device? Yes. Is it a drive? No. Does it look like a usb flash disk? Yes.